# C# DropDown List default value

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I am using this code to input values from a database table to a dropdown list:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TourImageID, new SelectList(Model.Images, "ImageID", "Filename", Model.TourImageID))
</div>
```

What i am trying to do is add an item to the top of the list, that is not present in the database table.

Something like `DROPDOWN LIST VALUES = (DEFAULT-ITEM) + (DATABASE-TABLE-ITEMS)`

is that possible? if so, how?

Comment: apologies in advance for the terrible description.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Model.Images` is of type `SelectList`, you can do something like this in your controller:

```
var query = UnitOfWork.GlobalImageLibraryRepository.Images.Select(x => new { x.ImageID, x.Filename });

viewModel.Images = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "ImageID", "Filename");
viewModel.Images.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "--Select--" });
```

I've assumed that you have a method in your GlobalImageLibraryRepository class that returns `IQueryable<Images>` like this:

```
public IQueryable<Images> Images { get { return dbcontext.Images; } }
```

So after all that, your view will look like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TourImageID, (SelectList)Model.Images, Model.TourImageID))
</div>
```

Comment: This is in my view, and `Model.Images` is where the images are stored i believe :(

Comment: Can you show the bit of controller code that populates the model before it's sent to the view?

Comment: `viewModel.Images = UnitOfWork.GlobalImageLibraryRepository.GetAll().ToList();` is this what you mean?